# How to get animation end notification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to do some action once animation ended.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.80f];
self.view.transform = 
CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(
                                 self.view.frame.origin.x, 
                                 480.0f + (self.view.frame.size.height/2)  // move the whole view offscreen
                                 );
[self.view setAlpha:0];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I have done animation like above, How to find out animation ended, so that I can do my action after that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.80f animations:^{
    self.view.transform =
    CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(
                                     self.view.frame.origin.x,
                                     480.0f + (self.view.frame.size.height/2)  // move the whole view offscreen
                                     );
    [self.view setAlpha:0];
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished){
        // your code
    }];
```

Answer (score 7):

Add this to your animation:

```
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(myAnimationEnded)];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
```

and this method will tell you when it stops;

```
- (void)myAnimationEnded{
     NSLog(@"animation ended");
}
```

Comment: Don't forget `[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];`.

Comment: I prefer this way of setting the animation properties, I don't like to wrap everything between `{}`.

Comment: Of course, my friend, I just thought it was obvious to set the delegate to self each time you need to interact.

Comment: Well, if he didn't even know how to set an animationDidStop selector, I guess he doesn't know he has to set the delegate for the animation neither.

Comment: Evil true, yeah, fortunately that's not for long, he'll learn it soon. There is a bit of time while I don't google for solutions.

Comment: Old good times when we were learning how to use Objective-C. :)

Comment: That nice moment when you answer questions that once upon a time you were googling for...

Answer (score 4):

Use the `UIView`'s `-animateWithDuration:animations:completion:` class method.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 animations:^{
        CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(
                                         self.view.frame.origin.x, 
                                         480.0f + (self.view.frame.size.height/2)  // move the whole view offscreen
                                         );
        [self.view setAlpha:0];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        //this block is called when the animation is over
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your code after `[UIView commitAnimations];`. The animation remains between the `beginAnimations` and the `commitAnimations`.

Comment: @Tejashwar I want to remove the view with animation, I have tried as you told, but its not removing view with animation.

Answer (score 0):

Not that `setAnimationDelegate`

> Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. If you are using the block-based animation methods, you can include your delegate’s start and end code directly inside your block.